# Optimising spatial mysql query with point

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, geospatial, mysql-5.7

I have two tables on MySQL 5.7 that look like this:

```
create table places
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    position point null comment 'Coordinates of the city.',

    constraint places_position_uindex
        unique (position)
);

create table place_names
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    place_id int not null comment 'ID of place in table places.',
    name char(255) not null comment 'Name of the place in the given language.',
    country char(255) not null comment 'Name of the place''s country in the given language.',
    language char(3) not null comment 'ISO 3 code of the language this record is in.'
);

create index place_names_language_index
    on place_names (language);

create index place_names_name_language_index
    on place_names (name, language);
```

And I'm building a query to fetch a given place's name based on the distance from a given point. I currently have:

```
SELECT
name,
ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(position, p.point) AS distance,
administration,
country
FROM place_names
JOIN places ON place_names.place_id = places.id
JOIN (
    SELECT
       POINT(?, ?) AS point
) AS p
WHERE language = 'ENG'
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10;
```

If I `EXPLAIN` this query I get:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | <derived2> | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 | 100 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | place_names | NULL | ref | place_names_language_index | place_names_language_index | 12 | const | 1368960 | 100 | NULL |
| 1 | PRIMARY | places | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | msdplaces.place_names.place_id | 1 | 100 | NULL |
| 2 | DERIVED | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | No tables used |

As you can see, the table is quite large (1368960 rows) and will become much larger in the future. I would like to reduce the lookup rows as much as possible (by limiting them, for example, to a radius of 80 km, or even just 1 lon/lat degree around the given point before computing the ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE between the point and the rows. Or whatever other optimisation could make the query faster, since at the moment it's unusably slow.

All I've found on the internet so far comes from before version 5.7, so it has to manually compute distances instead of using the native POINT datatype and the ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE function-these are much faster than handling trigonometry manually, so I'd like to keep them, but I'm not opposed to splitting the POINT column into separate latitude and longitude if that should bear an advantage.

How can I optimise this query such that table size will impact performance as little as possible?

**EDIT:**
I added a spatial index on `position`

```sql
create spatial index position
    on places (position);
```

and changed the query to the following to try and make use of the index, but it seems like it's not getting used at all:

```sql
explain select
name,
ST_Distance_Sphere(position, p.point) as distance,
administration,
country
FROM place_names
join places on place_names.place_id = places.id
join (
    select
       POINT(30.5315, 56.3396) as point
) as p
WHERE
      MBRContains(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((29.0 55.0, 29.0 57.0, 31.0 57.0, 29.0 57.0, 29.0 55.0))'), places.position)
and
      language = 'ENG'
order by distance
limit 10;
```

(Note that in order to add the index I had to make `position` NOT NULL.) The result:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | <derived2> | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 | 100 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | place_names | NULL | ref | place_names_language_index | place_names_language_index | 12 | const | 1368960 | 100 | NULL |
| 1 | PRIMARY | places | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | mydb.place_names.place_id | 1 | 100 | NULL |
| 2 | DERIVED | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | No tables used |

The result seems the same as without the MBRContains() part of the query and I still see that dreaded "rows = 1368960". As I understand it, that means the rows are not getting restricted by the clause at all. I also tried swapping `from` and `join` to have the main table be `places`, but nothing changes.

Comment: You may create spatial index and use MBRWithin() for pre-filtering. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-indexes.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html#function_mbrwithin

Comment: Alternatively you may divide your map to 80 km squares, pre-calculate square number for each point, and pre-filter by the point posess in the same or adjacent (by side or corner) square.

Comment: "find nearest":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

Comment: Use a spatial index and MBRContains. That will avoid the nasty table scan. Check out this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260757/mysql-8-not-using-spatial-index

Comment: @O.Jones I'm working on MySQL 5.7, the post you reference is MySQL 8.0. I have access to the point datatype but it does not look like I can take advantage of SRID (which I get the impression is an important part of MBR functions and spatial indexes-do tell if I'm wrong).

Comment: In MySQL 8.0 the geospatial extension can perform great-circle distance calculations when handed lat/long and the correct SRIDs. In MySQL 5,7 the distance calculations won't come out right, but you can still use MBRContains() and the index. You just have to set the bounding box longitude sizes correctly..

Comment: @O.Jones Could you elaborate on "won't come out right"? I don't need very precise outputs but what kind of inaccuracies should I expect?

Comment: Latitude lines get closer together as you get nearer the poles. So Cartesian distance calculations become inaccurate. Here's an explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318013/how-to-optimize-sql-query-geolocating-data/67440525#67440525

Comment: I've updated the question with an attempt to use MBRContains and a spatial index, please if you'd be so kind as to check the edited part.

Comment: Rearranging the tables in `FROM..JOIN..` should not matter -- the Optimizer will decide which order to do them in.  (`STRAIGHT_JOIN` forces the order, but that is usually counterproductive.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that to solve the issue, what I needed was to:

1. Make the `position` column NOT NULL (POINT does not support DEFAULT, so I manually set all null values to POINT(0, 0) and will have to do so when inserting records too). This is a requirement for the index:
2. `ALTER TABLE places ADD SPATIAL INDEX (position)`.
3. Use MBRContains() to restrict the query to fewer elements based on `position`. Of course, MBRWithin() would also work. In actuality I will have to construct the bounding box based on the latitude and longitude manually.

That alone didn't seem to work, but then I found out that the main issue was not on the spatial column but on the join: the place_id column had no index! Whoops.

So this is the final query I ended up with:

```sql
SELECT
p.id,
ST_Distance_Sphere(p.position, POINT(30.5315, 56.3396)) AS distance,
pn.name,
pn.administration,
pn.country
FROM (
    SELECT id, position
    FROM places
    WHERE MBRContains(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((29 55, 29 57, 31 57, 29 57, 29 55))'), position)
) p
JOIN place_names pn ON p.id = pn.place_id
WHERE pn.language = 'ENG'
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10;
```

Thanks to Rick James and Akina for the advice and pointers. Hopefully this will be of help to others passing by.

Answer (score 0):

What you have must scan all 1368960 points and check the distance to each one.  This is time consuming.

All optimizations involve limiting the search to a "bounding box".  The following shows a method using a `SPATIAL` index, plus 4 others.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

Comment: That method assumes the table stores latitude and longitude separately whereas in my case I have a single `position` column of type point. I could run that extracting x and y from points but i don't have an index with the results, so that would end up being extremely inefficient, right?

Comment: @theberzi - With "Point" you are primed for using a `SPATIAL` index.  See the option for that.  It is quite efficient, especially since you have "Points" already.  Let me know if you need further guidance.

Comment: Yes, I added a spatial index, but I can't seem to make use of it. Please check the EDIT part of my original question.

Comment: You might need floats instead of ints in that "from text" string.

Comment: And please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the `SPATIAL` index.

Comment: I added the code i used to add the index and updated the query and result. Unfortunately, changing the ints to floats didn't seem to work.

Comment: Changing ints to floats -- Did you get an error?  Or nothing changed?  Or something else?

Comment: Simply nothing changed.